# SQL Insert with ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am adding some new records to my table "flight" in Oracle database. However, I encountered a error which is called in valid character. May anyone help me to figure the error out of my insertion statement.

My Table creation statement is as follow.

```
 create table flight(
       FlightID integer NOT NULL,
       Airline char(20) NOT NULL,
       DepartCity char(20) NOT NULL,
       ArrivalCity char(20) NOT NULL,
       DepartTime timestamp NOT NULL,
       ArrivalTime timestamp NOT NULL,
       Class2Price integer NOT NULL,
       Class1Price integer NOT NULL,
       Class2Seats integer NOT NULL,
       Class1Seats integer NOT NULL,
       primary key (FlightID));
```

My insertion is as follow

```
insert into flight(FlightID, Airline, DepartCity, ArrivalCity, DepartTime, ArrivalTime,         Class2Price, Class1Price, Class2Seats, Class1Seats)
Values(2,'Pacific Airlines','Taipei','Osaka',to_timestamp('2014-12-01 08:15','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI'),to_timestamp('2014-12-01 13:15','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI'),4500,6000,2,6);
```

My JDBC JavaCode is as follow

```
stmt.execute("insert into flight(FlightID, Airline, DepartCity, ArrivalCity, DepartTime, ArrivalTime, Class2Price, Class1Price, Class2Seats, Class1Seats)"
                +"values("+ values+")");
```

where values is

```
   values =2,'Pacific Airlines','Taipei','Osaka',to_timestamp('2014-12-01 08:15','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI'),to_timestamp('2014-12-01 13:15','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI'),4500,6000,2,6
```

The error code are as follow

```
 3月 15, 2014 12:45:06 上午 database.application.DatabaseApplication load_data
```

SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:936)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:298)
at database.application.DatabaseApplication.load_data(DatabaseApplication.java:282)
at database.application.DatabaseApplication.Data_mani_menu(DatabaseApplication.java:106)
at database.application.DatabaseApplication.main_menu(DatabaseApplication.java:55)
at database.application.DatabaseApplication.main(DatabaseApplication.java:28)
```

Comment: Make sure , you *dont* use a _semicolon_ (`;`) in your insert query string in `JDBC`

Comment: Could you please add your java code snippet as well? and the exact error message itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is missing the final comma '`,`':

> DepartCity char(20) NOT NULL

**EDIT**: it also turned out that the insert statement string was containing tab chars instead of spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I got this error for the insert into statement instead of the create table statement. The missing comma is my typo in stackoverflow but not in my program. I have edited the above question with your advice.

Comment: Now it is ok on Oracle too - I mean, when ran by an SQL client.

Comment: I see. Maybe it is due to the error of java code. I use JDBC to connect the oracle database. I have also included the Java code in the  question. You may take a look. Thank you.

Comment: check what chars you have between 'Class1Price,     Class2Seats'; are just spaces or do you have tabs?

Comment: Yess you are right. That's the problem of tabs and spaces. I can now insert the record into the database without errors. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help you. I'll update the answer for future readers's sake